# Is there any way of not displaying the results of a code on the current file with org mode (spacemacs)?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

Let's say I have an `org` file with the following content on Spacemacs:

```
#+begin_src bash
  counter=0
  while [  $counter -lt 10 ]
  do 
      echo $counter
      let counter=counter+1 
  done
#+end_src
```

If I go to the line `#+begin_src bash` and press enter, I get the following result:

[image]

On Spacemacs it makes two actions:

- it prints the results of the code on the current file just like emacs does (not desired)
- it splits the window and prints the results of the code on the right side as well (desired)

I want to change it in a way that there will be no results printed on the current file, just the results on the split window. Is there any header I can use on the line `#+begin_src bash` to make that happen? If not, how can I execute the code in org mode so that I only see the results of the code on a split window?

Comment: I don't know what spacemacs does to display results in another window, but in regular emacs, adding `:results silent` as a header to a code block inhibits the addition of the results to the current buffer. Whether that will do what you want however, I have no idea.

Comment: @NickD Nice try, but it doesn't work for my case too... If I add `:results silent` both of the outputs don't display, including the one on the split window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to suppress the results by adding `:results silent` to the headline, we find that Spacemacs messages an error. So we can do `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to get a backtrace. From the backtrace we find that the error is triggered when calling `org-babel-open-src-block-result` (which is called by `org-open-at-point`, the command that got executed by pressing `RET`).

From inspecting (edebugging) `org-babel-open-src-block-result`, we find that that function reads the output from the `:RESULTS` block to open it in a separate buffer. Therefore, it is required to have the output printed first.

However, we can simply remove the :RESULTS subsequently by advising `org-babel-open-src-block-result` through evaluating the following line of code:

```lisp
(advice-add 'org-babel-open-src-block-result :after #'org-babel-remove-result)
```

Comment: So, `org-babel-open-src-block-result` is *not* called in regular emacs, only on spacemacs, correct?

Comment: @NickD Not by pressing `RET`. But also in regular Emacs, it is called when the cursor is on a headline, and you do `M-x org-open-at-point` (so the answer works (t)here also).

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the context by not reading the OP's question carefully enough. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: +1 for the answer and the analysis. That looks like a bug in `org-babel-open-src-block-result`: it shouldn't choke if no results are present (or at least it should fail with a less opaque error message).